# gives error of "The method or operation is not implemented" while getting HDD serial number

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to get the HDD serial number with below code...

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Management



    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        HDDCheck()
    End Sub

    Private Sub HDDCheck()
            Try
                Dim HDD_Serial As String
                 Dim hdd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
                For Each hd In hdd.Get
                    HDD_Serial = hd("SerialNumber")
                    If Not "20202020202020200332043354132314a5341" = HDD_Serial Then
                       Me.Close()
                    Else
                        Exit For
                    End If
                Next

            Catch ex As Exception

            End Try
        End Sub
```

but I am getting below error...

> System.NotImplementedException was caught   Message=The method or
>   operation is not implemented.

Same code runs on same machine on my previous applications , 
but this is new application I have written, this gives me an error...

What I am missing ?

Comment: Obvious question. Have you added a reference to System.Management and added an `Imports System.Management` line to your code? I did that and it edited the line `Dim hdd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")` to `Dim hdd As New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")` and it works fine for me.

Comment: Wow, thats awesome !!! Thanks a lot , it works like a charm !!!

Answer (score 0):

I just have to change of code

from

```
Dim hdd As New ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
```

to

```
Dim hdd As New Management.ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_DiskDrive")
```

Thanks [David Wilson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5413498/david-wilson)